# MongoDB-Stitch. Populate Method or similar methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, stitch

I have two collections, lets call them A and B. Collection A stores documents that hold an ObjectId of another document in collection B.

Ex: `{name: String, age: String, bObjectId: ObjectId}`

When I query for an item in collection A, I want to be able to populate the value of bObjectId so that I get back properties of that document in collection B. With mongoose this was possible by simply using the `populate` method. However, I don't see any methods available in Stitch that allows us to do something like that. Could anyone share their experience with solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

**You can use lookup **

```
db.inventory.aggregate([

    {
        $lookup:{
            from:'orders',
            localField:'sku',
            foreignField:'item',
            as:'inventory_doc'

        }

    }

])
```

Comment: It looks like $lookup is not supported by my version of stitch. Do you happen to have a link to the docs on this?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/